# How do I delete these faces?

Tags: modeling, faces

I'm trying to make the pants of my character. I selected these vertex, used Looptools>Circle, rotated it and moved the selected circle to align with the reference, but when I delete the face it doesn't delete the whole thing and it looks off. What am I doing wrong? The last image is my goal.[image: Actual Goal][image: Selected vertex]

[image: Selected Vertex]

[image: Looptool Circle, Rotated and Moved up]

[image: After face deleted]

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you please share the bottom of your character so that we can give a try? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Sure! I've included the blender file.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you have overlapping vertices, so select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*. Also your selection will cause faces overlapping, you should select all these faces instead:

[image]

Then inset and *LoopTools > Circle*:

[image]

After extrusion and bevel:

[image]

Comment: Thank you it worked. I tried to merge distance but I forgot to select all before doing so, I was only merging the selected parts.